# It is possible to keep multiple jquery widgets in scrolling div

Tags: jquery, widget

Is it possible to position/keep   multiple jquery widgets(dialogs) with in a scrolling div element?

Because, in one of our application,  we need to open multiple widgets (with width:400, height:300) dynamicaly.

And I want to make all widgets visible.

And I using the position property in css to position the widget based on some reference element.

The first four  widgets are positioned correctly and it is visible perfectly.

The rest of the widgets are overlapping on each other.

So is it possible to keep all widgets with In on another  div with overflow/scrolling ? or is there any other alternate solution available?

Below is my javascript code

`

```
var refTagOffset = $("#loadWidgetHere span[id='refEle']").offset();
var offSetX = refTagOffset.left;
var offSetY = refTagOffset.top;
var widgetGapX = 50;
var widgetGapY = 200;
var dialogWidth = 500;
var dialogHeight = 360;

var len = '20' // dynamic one

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {     
    var widgetDivID = "widget_" + i;
    divContent = '';    


    divContent += '<div id="'+widgetDivID+'" style="width:450px; height: 300px;"></div>';

    $("#loadWidgetHere").append(divContent);

    $172("#"+widgetDivID).dialog(dialogOptions).dialogExtend(dialogExtendOptions);

    $172("#"+widgetDivID).dialog('option','position',[offSetX,offSetY]);

    if( (i+1)%2 == 0 && i != (len-1) ) {
        offSetX = refTagOffset1.left;
        offSetY += dialogHeight+widgetGapY;
    } else
        offSetX += dialogWidth+widgetGapX;
}

 </script>`
```

And the HTML tags are,

```
`<div style="overflow:auto;width:800px;height:700px;" id="loadWidgetHere">
    <span id="refEle"></span>
</div>`
```

Thanks in Advance,
Madeswaran.

Comment: you will not want to use the same selector for all widgets for example setting `$("#content").dialog()` twice, the rest shouldn't be trouble, so make sure this div where they will be inserted have other divs to wrap your widgets

Comment: Actually, i am appending all of the widget divs in to a div which i was set as overflow:auto property. And i have the reference span with in the main div. `<div style="overflow:auto;width:800px;height:700px;" id="loadWidgetHere">
  <span id="refEle"></span>
 </div>` . But the first four widgets are visible perfectly. But the rest all overlapping on one another.

Comment: would you mind setting up a fiddle?